# unable to remove div inserted by jquery

Tags: jquery

am trying to remove a div inserted by jquery onclick. for some reason its just not working i tried remove(); hide(); css(); empty(); they all are just not working.. so here's my js function

```
function callme()
{
var content = '<div id="floating_box" class="fb">'
'sdfsdfsdfsdfsfsddsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsd'
'</div>';
jQuery('body.floating_box').empty();
jQuery('body').append(content);
}
```

and here is my html code

```
<div id="notify" class="nn" onclick="callme()">
 <span id="nbox" class="nb">
<img src="gn16.png">
<span id="ntext" class="nt">23</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This JavaScript doesn't even execute. You can also not refer to the content because it's not inserted yet, it's only a string.

Comment: you're emptying the body??? `jQuery('body.floating_box').empty()`

Comment: @Reigel, indeed... didn't even notice that. I think he's confusing jQuery selector syntax with HTML 4 ID lookups.

Comment: @MvanGeest, then look at the answer of opatut below.. :)

Comment: @Reigel, I'd say facepalm, or is that considered rude?

Comment: @Reigel, not the body just the .floating_box

Comment: @MvanGeest, its inserted but am unable to remove it

Comment: @clonex1 we need more codes, and more explanations.. in the html, is that all you have??

Comment: @clonex1, then consider the answer by Gaby. The way to select it is `jQuery('#floating_box')`, then use `.remove()`.

Comment: @clonex1 - I completely misunderstood the question the first time around, but now I think I've got a pretty elegant solution using `toggle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3y7Cz/show/light/)

```
function callme()
{
    var content = '<div id="floating_box" class="fb">' +
    'sdfsdfsdfsdfsfsddsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsd' +
    '</div>';
    jQuery('#floating_box').toggle();
    if (!$('#floating_box').length)
      jQuery('body').append(content);
}
```

Comment: just tried your edited code on my local/remote site http://passivenet.com/2/, its still not working

Comment: that worked. 
thanks Gaby thanks everyone for your help
saved my day

Answer (score 2):

use `jQuery('#floating_box')`

You are using an id, but are not referencing it as one ..

You need to use the `.remove()` method, because with the `.empty()` you are creating multiple elements with the same id which is **invalid**

Have a look at this [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/WJf75/)

---

***Update***

After the comment, i see that you want the 1st time you click to create the element, and subsequent clicks to just show/hide it ..

use this code

```
$('#notify').click(
function (){
    if ($('#floating_box').length > 0) // it exists
    {
        jQuery('#floating_box').toggle(); // show/hide\
    }
    else //does not exist 1st time only..
    {
        var content = '<div id="floating_box" class="fb">popup</div>';
        jQuery('body').append(content);
    }
});
```

and remove the `onclick="callme"` from the element..

Comment: But he **hasn't even inserted the `content` string in the DOM**! Why should that ID exist?

Comment: @MvanGeest, he wants to be able to remove previously added content, and then re-enter it ... (*it is on a click event*)

Comment: Could be... but there's no `#floating_box` in his HTML example.

Comment: yeah, i fixed that part. even so its still not removing

Comment: Not in the order you're executing it... you're first removing it, then appending it...

Comment: @clonex, use `jQuery('#floating_box').remove();`

Comment: There's no `#floating-box` in the code, since it was inserted with Javascript.

Comment: @clonex1, your code is re-adding what you remove.. what *exactly* do you want to happen when you click ?

Comment: @clonex1 it is... you are just hypnotized... when it was removed, another one was added... see this demo to illustrate http://jsfiddle.net/QvBmC/

Comment: @Gaby, when i click in the first time content is appened (which is nice thing)
when is reclick to have it removed - its not removing just stays there -

Comment: @clonex1, it does not jsut stay there .. it is removed and re-added..  you want to show it on one click and hide it on the next ? .. why did you never mention that :) ?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = '<div id="floating_box" class="fb">' +
'sdfsdfsdfsdfsfsddsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsd' +
'</div>';
```

See the **+**  ??

```
jQuery('body.floating_box').remove(); // edit: sorry my mistake
jQuery('body #floating_box').remove(); // better? should remove all elements within <body> with the id "floating_box"
```

Should be just fine.

Comment: the OP is emptying the body, and now you are removing the body... wow!

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `body.floatingbox` means "all the bodies with the class floatingbox".

Comment: But there's only one `body`, and it presumably doesn't have the `floatingbox` class, so the `remove()` does nothing.

Comment: i tried all the possible id/class combination that is possible and not possible. but its just not working. here's the new js code after adjustment:
function callme()
{
    var content = '<div id="floating_box" class="fb">' +
    'sdfsdfsdfsdfsfsddsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsd' +
    '</div>';
    jQuery('.fb').remove();
    jQuery('body').append(content);
}

and its still not working too... 
i spent that last 3 hours trying to remove this div its just dont wanna go

Comment: @opatus, i tried that too... no luck
u can check the code that am trying to get to work @ http://passivenet.com/2/

Comment: hey it works...
you remove the blue box with "sdfsdfsdf,..." and add another one with exactly the same content....
Try to insert some random stuff, you'll see it changes everytime you click the link

Comment: @opatut, that's not the purpose of remove isn't it!
i just need to have that div vanishes on the second click

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing the floating_box being removed because a new version of the floating_box div is added whenever you call the callme function.

```
 function callme() {
     var $floatingbox = jQuery("#floating_box");
     if ( $floatingbox.length ) {
         $floatingbox.remove();
     }
     else {
        var content = '<div id="floating_box" class="fb">' +
            'sdfsdfsdfsdfsfsddsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsd' +
            '</div>';  
        jQuery('body').append(content);  
     }
 }
```

This will check whether the floating_box div exists, and remove it otherwise add it.